# the attempt to connect to the Tor anonymous network Please wait....failed - in a decryptor software

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, network-configuration

I am Using a Decryptor Software in that, i am getting the following message

"the attempt to connect to the Tor anonymous network Please wait....faile "

Please help me in this regard

Comment: We're going to need more information, I've never heard of this software. Do you have any logs of Tor output?